# How to automatically generate circular thumbnails from a rectangular, fluid image's center for a website?

Tags: html, css, image

I've been searching quite a lot for an answer to this question and can't seem to find anything reliable. The issue is this: I have an image in a web page whose size I don't know until run time. I want to be able to create a circular crop of this image taken from the center of the image even if I don't know it's size until run time. I also want to be able to be able to resize this image while maintaining its circular shape. Is this possible using CSS? More importantly is it bad practice? Should I instead just use some kind of image processing software to generate the required images and hardcode them into the website? If so anything easy I can use to generate these instead of using photoshop to make them manually myself?

TLDR: I'd like to be able to do whats on this website but without hardcoding pixel values into the image size.

http://sixrevisions.com/css/circular-images-css/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div a square height/width and apply the image as a `background-image` and use `background-size: cover;` to have the image be responsive to the div and `background-position: center center;` to center the image vertically and horizontally so that the "crop" is from the center.

square crop

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1980294624/DJT_Headshot_V2_400x400.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

portrait

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Hillary_Rodham_Clinton-cropped.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

landscape

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.dailystormer.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/obama.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My attempts to solve this problem were pretty similar I think the only thing I was missing was using vh instead of %. Silly me.